# Infinite Factorial Sum

Tags: limits, summation

Evaluate-
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{r!^{2}}$$.
Is it possible to find the sum?Tried bringing it to integral form, using concepts of power series known to me, simplifying sum, but could not simplify.  Will Stirling's Approximation be of use?

Comment: Assuming you mean $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \dfrac{1}{(r!)^2}$$ then Wolframalpha gives the limit as $I_0(2)-1$ where $I_0(n)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe how do we reach the limit?

Comment: @JAYRS I am not sure. But, your question did not indicate you had looked at Wolframalpha to check to see if it could find a limit. If Wolframalpha can find it, it is likely that it is possible (it is unlikely but not impossible that Wolframalpha is wrong)

Comment: The Maclaurin series of $I_0(x)$ is well-known: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x/2)^{2k}/(k!)^2$. $I_0$ being an entire function, it converges to $I_0(x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is impossible, just believe on computational intelligence

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(r!)^2}=I_0(2)-1\approx1.27959...$$here $I_n(z)$ is the Modified Bessel Function of the First Kind. More information can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

Comment: In general we have that$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k!)^2}=I_0(2\sqrt{z})$$for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ which follows directly from the series expansion of $I_0(z)$